# How do they prevent viruses from infecting every computer on the internet?

Tags: internet, virus

How is it possible to defend against 0-day exploits? Is it possible that something can infect everything connected to the internet?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://superuser.com/help) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to (somewhat) mitigate the risks of 0-days by ensuring your security is built up out of layers, and by sticking to principles of least privilege.  For example, using a firewall as well as a password and multi-factorial authentication (each could provide an additional obstacle) and by limiting the scope of access you limit the ability for a 0-day to be exploited.

Similarly, doing things like removing attachments from emails and limiting the ability to click on links can limit the ability to initiate a compromise, as can av software and as blockers.

It is almost impossible for something to affect everything connected to the Internet as there are different usage cases and different competing hardware, software,  standards and way of doing things.

What could happen (and did happen in the early days of the Internet: Google the RTM worm) is that enough of the Internet could be compromised that the mass of traffic could cripple it. This would be manageable over time as providers kick the offending traffic generators off their networks. There are also DDoS protection services and, of course, sophisticated detection and management algorithms. So while this could hurt for a brief time, its not a doomsday scenario.